# how we kept newly inserted row between two existing rows at the position of insert after save in bounded DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datagridview

I tried to insert new row between two existing rows in datagridview (already bound to database) I got success but issue is that when I enter a data in that blank row and click on save that accounts are going last but I want that account at same position where it inserted.

My code

```
        int idx = DGMaratha.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        var table = (DataTable)DGMaratha.DataSource;
        var row = table.NewRow();
        table.Rows.InsertAt(row, idx);
```

Comment: You arent supposed to care where records are inserted into the db.  If you want to *display* them in a certain order you need an Order By clause.  You can add a DisplayOrder column to the DB or to the SQL to control the order by session

Comment: Data is unordered unless there is a orderby instruction.  Remember that phrase....remember that phrase.